# How would I make a div containing the image I got from an online json?

Tags: javascript, html, json

So I want to grab the link off of https://nekos.life/api/v2/img/meow and the image on my site. I saw on the official nekos main page that they put the image on the front without doing a script. So something like that would be nice. If you check on the site, it is in a small box, but I basically want that but full-screened so I can use the API easier.

***If there is not enough detail, COMMENT PLEASE about the question.***

Thanks!

Comment: "I saw on the official nekos main page that they put the image on the front without doing a script". It's called template engine, where the logic (i.e randomizing image) was performed on server side and it would render pure HTML every time a visitor hit the route. Confirmed on its [github repo](https://github.com/Nekos-life/neko-website).

Comment: Ok, I have looked on the repo, but I haven't been able to find the index.html.... if you can post another link here that would be great! @yogski

Comment: Take a look at  https://github.com/Nekos-life/neko-website/blob/master/templates/neko.html#L52, it's the template engine used for website in question. You will notice unusual syntax `src="{{ img_url }}"`. It is a variable, where the value is determined by logic in server.

In a nutshell, you need the script to put URL into your `<img>` tag. Either do it using server with template engine, or using javascript as others have answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined all of your into a shorter one! Thanks!

```
<script>
function Get(yourUrl){
    var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); // a new request
    Httpreq.open("GET",yourUrl,false);
    Httpreq.send(null);
    return Httpreq.responseText;          
}
var div = document.getElementById('myImg');
var json = JSON.parse(Get("https://nekos.life/api/v2/img/meow"));
div.innerHTML = "<img src='"+json.url+"'/>";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Title of you site
    </title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div>
       <img id="myImg" src="" alt="You can have other details added"></img>
    </div>
  </body>
  
  <script>
    let response = await fetch('https://nekos.life/api/v2/img/meow');
    let data = await response.json();
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = data.url;
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it gives me an `(unknown)` for src... as shown [here](https://imgur.com/a/q5HOJnM)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id='container'></div> <!-- THIS DIV HOLDS THE IMAGE-->
<script>
var div = document.getElementById('container'); //change to actaul id of div on your site
var url = 'https://nekos.life/api/v2/img/meow'; //url of image
var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status === 200) {
        callback(null, xhr.response);
      } else {
        callback(status, xhr.response);
      }
    };
  xhr.send();
};
getJSON(url, callback);
function callback(n, data) {
  div.innerHTML = "<img src='"+data.url+"'/>";
}
</script>
```

Comment: the div adjusts to the image height and width

Comment: Ok, yes this works, but if it did not use a script that would be great!! Thanks tho!!

Comment: you would have to change the json link to an image to make it not use a script tag